# setting up a server for local small office

Tags: networking

I am very new in networking and setting up server. I have only used XAMPP to develop my site locally on my desktop computer. I did some researches and learn about all those network equipment online, but I found myself still confused about what I need to do to set up a server between computers. So I hope I can find the answers from experts. I have 4 computers in my office, and I am trying to create a local network that allows all 4 computers to access the files and localhost in the desktop computer.

1.) I have a modem and a router. My desktop computer and the other 2 computers are using wireless while my sister's computer is using cable that connects to the modem. In order for my sister and the other computers to access my files and localhost, do I need to plug all of the computers into a switch?

2.) I have read online that people set up port forwarding to allow others to access their website online. But right now I am just trying to make a local files and web server, do I need to set up port forwarding as well?

I am using Windows Vista and XAMPP. I couldn't solve any of the questions and confusion after 1 week of looking through online. So if anyone has a detailed guide for setting local file/web server, that will help me so much and thank you for your time as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You do not need a switch for setting up a server. An switch is just a device that basicly expands the amount cabled network connections you have. Most routers come often with 4 LAN ports and one WAN(probably conencted to your modem).

If you have lets say, 5 computers that needs a cabled connection. You will need a switch to be able to connect all those computers at the same time.

---

2) You only need to do port forwarding if you want others to connect from **outside** your local network. If you want to put a website up on a server, you will need to port forward port 80 (the port for http) to your servers local IP.

All port forwaring does is to say to your router that if it gets a packet of data with this port number to your **public IP**, then send it to this spesific **local IP** adress (your server with XAMPP). If you don't port forward, the router doesent know what local ip adress to send the packet of data to, then it just discards it, which means others cant access your website.

If you want to open your website from outside your local network, and have port forwarded your router. You probably want to setup a domain with DDNS (dynamic domain name system).

What that does is that people can write something like "www.google.com" instead of your public ip adress. A good site for that is: http://www.no-ip.com . Keep in mind that if you don't want to add a domain and just use the ip adress, your routers public IP address may change over time. Unless you have ordered a static IP address from your ISP (Internet service provider).

---

For your file server i would suggest a **FileZilla FTP Server** (FTP = File Transport Protocoll). Set this up on your server machine and follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=251TQq98zmo . Then after you have set up and configured your FTP server, you can connect your clients to the server.

I would suggest this guide to connect your other machines to the FTP server:
http://www.wintuts.com/Map-Network-Drive

Keep in mind if you want to access your FTP server from outside your network you will need to port forward both port 20 and 21. For security reasons i will strongly suggesting a password on your FTP server, unless you want anyone to connect to it.

Hope this helped!
-Kad

(PS: just comment on this post if something is unclear, or have further questions! :D  )

Comment: Thank you so much for putting everything in details. I will try to set it up right now. If I have questions, I will comment on this post but thank you once again.